# Different display on large monitors

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I would like to have different displays on my website. I already handled smartphones, tablets, and desktops, but I would something for large screens, and I'm not talking only in terms of resolution. I want the display to be different on screens over 21". It shouldn't look the same on a 15" laptop even though they both have the same resolution.

I've tried to use media queries based on pixel density but I'm getting mixed results, so I'm not sure if it's the best approach. I've tried this :

```
@media screen and (max-resolution: 115dpi){
  /* CSS rules */
 }
```

I'm not having the results I wanted though. I'm testing on a 23" monitor with a resolution of 1920x1080 and a pixel density of `94.53` , and a 13" MacBook with a resolution of 1440x900 and a pixel density of `127.68`. However, the display is the same on both devices, but it seems to work on some other laptops with different resolutions. So I'm getting confused.

What am I missing? Is using pixel density the best approach? Otherwise what other choice do I have?

Thanks

Comment: What result do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I'm not sure I understood the question. I want to find write different CSS rules for monitors having a certain size, and again I'm not talking about resolution only.

Comment: You could maybe use the `em` unit?

Comment: @PascalGoldbach can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: I found this link : https://css-tricks.com/optimizing-large-scale-displays/ it explains how to optimise the website on large screens.

Comment: @PascalGoldbach That's interesting, but in this article they tackle high resolution displays. Is this the only way to proceed? I mean the display would still be the same whether we are on a 15" laptop or a 23" monitor as long as they have the same resolution.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are missing an expression in your media query, which uses the `min-width` media feature:

> The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface
>   of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the
>   width of the page box on a printer).

---

Add another `and` logical operator followed by the `min-width` media feature and the width of the output device, usually in pixels.

---

**Example:**

`@media screen and (min-width:1680px) and (max-resolution: 115dpi) {}`

Answer (score 0):

People use that for serving hi-res images, and it is still detected on desktop displays.

To make sure mobile devices render the page the width of the device, you need to add the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

The reason people still query viewport with , i.e. @media all and (max-width: 320px) is because 320 pixels is still 320 px no matter what pixel density. It will be the same size.